# Strange order in histogram in r

Tags: r, histogram

I am using the following code to create a histogram for a variable that scales from 1 to 10.

```
mydata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Q32_1))+
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1, fill = "lightblue", col = "black") +
  labs(x= "my variable", y= "Frequency") + 
  ggtitle("")
```

The strange issue here is that 10 comes after 1. so the order is like 1, 10, 2, 3, etc. Here's the picture: [click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5UYy.png). I just want to move 10 to the end of the x-axis.

I'd appreciate any help I could get here.

Comment: Probably `Q32_1` is not numeric. Try `ggplot(aes(as.numeric(Q32_1))) + ....`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you were right. It is not numeric. The problem is solved. The only issue now is the x-axis doesn't show all the numbers. There are only 2.5, 5, 7.5, and 10. Do you know how to deal with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the variable `Q32_1` is stored as character. If you want to display all the values in `Q32_1` on X-axis convert them to factor.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydata,aes(factor(Q32_1))) +
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1, fill = "lightblue", col = "black") +
  labs(x= "my variable", y= "Frequency") + 
  ggtitle("")
```